# How to add a nullable column as part of primary composite key of the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table with data on production:

```
CREATE TABLE VerifiedUsers (
    Mobile varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (Mobile,Email)
);
```

We have a new requirement where we need to save user's unique device-id in this table so that anyone we uniquely identify the user on basis of (Mobile, Email, DeviceId) and not (Mobile, Email).

This new column DeviceId has to be Nullable as we can't ensure that every client would send us the DeviceId. On the other hand, we have to make it a part of Primary Key as we can now have multiple rows with same (Mobile,Email) but different DeviceId.

How should we solve this. Should we solve it by giving some default value to DeviceId in case it's null?

Comment: Instead of null, why don't you just use an empty string for unknown device ID?

Comment: That will work as long as a combination of mobile + email will only have one device. Otherwise, you may have to create a trigger on before insert to enter a value for this column.

Comment: @Barmar: Looks really simple. I believe I missed it. I think inserting it as empty string when i don't have device ID should work

Comment: This all seems wrongly designed. You should have separate table for each unique identification: `email->name`, `mobile->name`, and `deviceID->name`. Why do you need unique combinations of different methods?

Comment: This just seems a little off. "We have to make it a part of Primary Key as we can now have multiple rows with same (Mobile,Email) but different DeviceId" is just wrong. If the primary key is on (Mobile, Email) already, you can never have multiple rows with the same (Mobile,Email) pair; that is the point of primary/unique keys. You can currently have 5000 records with the same email if each has a different mobile, and 1000 records with the same mobile if they have different email, at the same time. It sounds to me more like you need a separate unique key for each field.

Comment: @Uueerdo: We have to change primary key now. The new data can have same (mobile, email) with different deviceId.

Comment: Ah, by "can have" you mean "should be allowed to have"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE VerifiedUsers (
    VerifiedUserId int auto_increment primary key,
    Mobile varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    DeviceId varchar(255),  -- or whatever
    Name varchar(255),
    UNIQUE (Mobile, Email, DeviceId)
);
```

The components of a primary key cannot be nullable.  Having a single auto-increment column as a primary key is convenient for many reasons:

- Useful for foreign key references.
- Keeps track of insert order.
- Only uses 4 bytes (or 8 bytes if the table is really, really big).

Comment: But we already have this table on production with million data rows

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, a default value wouldn't be any more helpful than it just staying null.  Either way, both values don't help with identifying the user.  An auto increment primary key would be an ideal solution, but that would only be if that was allowed in your situation.